# arbotix_ros can not detect servos via arbotix-m controller

Tags: ros, arbotix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I am using ros indigo and ubuntu 14.04. I have Phantomx Pincher arm connected to the computer via FTDI USB cable.

I clone arbotix_ros and I did catkin_make properly.

BUT I can not detect my servos (dynamixel ax-12a) thru arbotix-m, I am getting the following output,

anyone can help me please ??

I even tried arbotix_gui I got the window but the servos don't move.

```
    imr@IMR-PC:~$ sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0    
    [sudo] password for imr: 
     imr@IMR-PC:~$ arbotix_terminal
     ArbotiX Terminal --- Version 0.1
    Copyright 2011 Vanadium Labs LLC
        >>  ls
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 
    >>  ls
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271596/arbotix_ros-can-not-detect-servos-via-arbotix-m-controller/) by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out that I have to upload `ros.ino` to the `arbotix-m` board after making sure that the baud rate should be `Serial.begin(115200);`

---

Originally posted by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0